# Keep XAMPP default page as developing website

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

I am preparing to create my portfolio site and this is something I always thought. I find XAMPP default admin page useful in some ways to me, but as I am developing website, I can't access it any more.

I want to know is there a way to keep XAMPP default page as I am developing other websites.

I know I can setup virtual hosts for several websites, but is it same for XAMPP? I have done virtual host one time as work. At, first it didn't work(what was CakePHP app), but later I have managed to make it work.

UPDATE: 
So I found out this post about [Hosting multiple local sites with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660066/hosting-multiple-local-sites-with-xampp) and have edited my Virtual Host config file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost/xampp
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>
```

My windows host file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost/xampp
```

For now, accessing both `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.0.1/xampp` redirect me to XAMPP home page, which is in C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/

When I access `localhost`, browser redirects me to index.php file(As `127.0.0.1` also should), which is for testing purposes in htdocs folder. However if I try to access `localhost/xampp` I get error in Chrome - "This webpage has a redirect loop".

I have no idea how to progress on from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out answer. THe issue was with my naming of xampp admin page domain, instead of using someting, which include `localhost` for xampp page, I had to use something else, as it will not conflict when using your own naming.

So my hosts file now:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       xampp-admin
```

And Apache Virtual Host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xampp-admin
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This part(below) didn't change anything, I added, because I saw it in examples, but I still have no idea, what it's useful to:

```
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

Still, maybe someone can suggest me more conventional name for Xampp admin page?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to is place this at the top of your httpd-vhost.conf before other virtual host configurations.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard/"
    ServerName xampp.admin
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```