# CSS not loading despite rewrite rules that should exclude the front controller from files that exist

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am seriously struggling to understand how to achieve what I want in my PHP/HTML and in my `.htaccess` file.

I want most of my URLs to be handled by `index.php` unless it's a directory that exists, in which case I want to deliver the directory. Otherwise I want the URL to appear as `www.example.co.uk/whatever` and to deliver index.php?page=whatever. I want a few cases of `www.example.co.uk/this/that` which would go to index.php?page=this&morestuff=that

I have my CSS files in a directory `/design/` in the root of my webspace, and so I employ this in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design/css-design.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design/checkout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design/css-mediaplayer.css">
```

However if I type `www.example.co.uk/whatever/morethings`, the CSS isn't loaded. Even though `index.php` is running, everything else thinks the current directory is the /whatever directory and not the root directory, and so the references to the href="design/css..." don't work

Can I stop that happening but continue to have the URLs appear as `www.example.co.uk/this/that`? Or do I have to change the code so that my CSS, images and other bits and bobs are always referred to with a full URL because of this relative directory problem?

If I have rewrite it, that means the code in my localhost Apache server at home has to be different from that later uploaded to the web, because I'm referring to CSS and images etc on my PC, not on the web!

My `.htaccess` file appears as follows. As far as delivering files, directories, sending things to `index.php` with either one or two parameters it works:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
# Strip trailing slashes and redirect if there isn't a directory of that name:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]
#
# If the file or directory exists, allow it through verbatim and stop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
#
# If the request is of the form /xxx/yyy, send two parameters:
Rewriterule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&morestuff=$2 [L]
#
# Reach this point if zero or one argument, and so:
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

All the rewrite rules appear to behave as expected for both `www.example.co.uk/whatever` and for `www.example.co.uk/whatever/more`, and for stripping trailing slashes.

However if I type `www.example.co.uk/whatever/more`, the CSS isn't loaded because references in the HTML to the `/design/` or `/images/` directories are no longer valid: they would need to be ../design and ../images.

Comment: Ah...after hours of battling with this I've realised, eventually, upon spotting something elsewhere on the web that I need to add Rewriterule .*/assets/(.*+)$ assets/$1 [L] if I put all my CSS and other stuff in a directory tree assets/. Then a single rewriterule directs everything to the right place always.

Comment: I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  The CSS wasn't loading bcs you're using relative links - from `/whatever/morethings` you've told the browser to look for `design/css-design.css`, so it requests `/whatever/morethings/design/css-design.css`.  You can avoid that by simply making the reference absolute: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/design/css-design.css">`.  Likewise including rewrite rules testing for things that exist and not rewriting them is pointless - just test for things that *don't* exist, and actually rewrite those.

Comment: Agree with the above.  Your problem has nothing to do with rewrite rules.  You are missing a slash at the start of your CSS href.

Comment: So why doesn't it work on my localhost Apache server on my PC, then? I can do as you've suggested when uploading to my website host, but I am runninp xampp server on my PC and localhost set to C:\localhost and in there I have directories for more than one different website, so the one in question is localhost/www.mydomain.co.uk/. If I remove the rewriterule for design assets directories and then put slashes in all the references as suggested, it doesn't work at home!

Comment: "*I have directories for more than one different website*" - you didn't mention this in your question, so the advice you got doesn't cover that situation.  In any case, as you've already found out, hosting the same site in totally different environments is not so easy.  Your best bet is to make your local/dev env as similar toproduction as possible.  You might search for something like "*XAMPP multiple websites*" to get started, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660066/hosting-multiple-local-sites-with-xampp